# C# overload resolution with IList<T> and IReadOnlyList<T>

Tags: c#, overloading, overload-resolution

I have a method which I'd like to take all list-like objects in my solution. Before .NET 4.5, this was simple:

```cs
public static T Method<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    // elided
}
```

However, .NET 4.5 introduced `IReadOnlyList<T>`, which this method should also apply to.

I can't just change the signature to take an `IReadOnlyList<T>`, as there are places where I apply the method to something specifically typed as an `IList<T>`.

The algorithm can't run on `IEnumerable<T>`, and it's used too frequently (and with too large objects) to take an `IEnumerable<T>` and create a new `List<T>` on every call.

I've tried adding an overload:

```
public static T Method<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list)
{
    // elided
}
```

... but this won't compile for anything which implements both interfaces (`T[]`, `List<T>`, and numerous other types), as the compiler can't determine which method to use (particularly annoying as they have the same body, so it doesn't matter).

I don't want to have to add overloads of `Method` which take `T[]`, and `List<T>`, and every other type which implements both interfaces.

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: use `IEnumerable<T>`? or `ICollection<T>` if you want the ability to specify the collections should support add/remove operations

Comment: I don't think you'll achieve what you need unless you resort to using `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IList<T> and IReadOnlyList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838122/ilistt-and-ireadonlylistt) --  not an _exact_ dupe of the goal, but same underlying issue and tons of work-arounds and ideas in the answers.

Comment: Ric and Jim - I've edited the question to explain why that won't work. Sorry I forgot to mention it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SimonW: Sorry, but you're out of luck here. As long as `IList<>` doesn't implement `IReadOnlyList<>`, but all implementations implementing both interfaces you are just in trouble.

Comment: @mjwills I think that might be the best bet, although there are a lot of  `IList<T>` in the solution so it'd be a big job.

Comment: Be lucky if all is in one solution. In that case, just search replace and compile. Fix all errors. Done.

Comment: You can accept `IEnumerable<T>` BUT check if what has been passed implements `IList` or `IReadOnlyList` or whatever other interfaces you might need. If it does - do whatever you need using `IList` or `IReadOnlyList`. If not - construct new `List` from `IEnumerable` and do what you need with it. That way you won't have perfomance penalty from constructing new list from `IEnumerable` when it's not necessary.

Comment: Since you won't actually find an satisfying answer with the information provided, I would be very interested in the details of the algorithm and see if it really cannot be refactored to take an `IEnumerable<T>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be one of those occasions where actually checking the runtime type is useful:

```
public static T Method<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source is IList<T> list)
        return Method(list);

    if (source is IReadOnlyList<T> readOnly)
        return Method(readOnly);

    return Method(source.ToList() as IList<T>);
}

private static T Method<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list) { ... }
private static T Method<T>(IList<T> list) { ... }
```

You still have to duplicate code in the sense that you need seperate implementations for `IList` and `IReadOnlyList` because there is no common interface you can leverage, but you at least avoid the ambigous call issue.

Comment: I like your approach. I have a similar problem for a binary search (lower bound) extension method. However, the point is that binary search uses O(log(n)) instead of O(n), so calling .ToList() kind of cancels the functionality. Do you have a recommendation for that case? I thought about throwing a NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 2):

Your likely best bet is to do a global search and replace of `IList` to `IReadOnlyList`. If there are no compiler errors then you should be fine.

*You should only receive compiler errors if you are using `IList.Add` - which is foolhardy anyway, since arrays don't support `Add`.*

Comment: The problem is that `IList<T>` does not implement directly or indirectly `IReadOnlyList<T>` so this solution is not valid. [IList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yep, I am aware of that - thanks for mentioning it @InBetween. But given the OP appears to be using inbuilt types (`List<T>`, arrays etc) - they **do** implement both interfaces. You are right in the more general sense - this solution won't work for _everybody_, since they may be using a type that implements `IList` but not `IReadOnlyList`. Nonetheless, even in those cases, the compiler should pick up the issue instantly (hence my `compiler errors` comment in my answer).

Comment: ah..sorry. I falsely thought `List<T>` didn't implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`. Yeah this could be a lesser evil, but it all depends on how its used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the code of Method calling?
What if you create a method like this:

```
    public static T1 Method<T1, T2>(T2 list) where T2 : IList<T1>, IReadOnlyList<T1>
    {
        return default(T1);
    }
```

In this case the calls look like this:

```
List<string> listA = new List<String>();
ReadOnlyCollection<string> listB = listA.AsReadOnly();

string outVar1 = Method<string, List<string>>(listA);
string outVar2 = Method<string, ReadOnlyCollection<string>>(listB);
```

Another way to create two extension methods for IList and IReadOnlyList this way:

```
    public static T Test<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    public static T Test<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
```

And call them like this:

```
    string outVar1 = (listA as IReadOnlyList<string>).Test();
    string outVar2 = (listB as IList<string>).Test();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your best solution is to look into why your algorithm can't run on an IEnumerable and change that. Are you using `IList<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>` -specific members that you could replace with members available in `IEnumerable<T>`? Eg:

```
// instead of
int c = list.Count;

// use
int c = list.Count();
```

---

EDIT: ignore the nonsense below. I am leaving it so that the comments continue to make sense.

You should not implement both `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` in any class. The only additional members in the `IList` specification are for writing to the list. You would not need to do that if your list is read only. I think you need to change any classes that implement both so that the correct method can be selected when using them.

However, As all members of `IReadOnlyList<T>` are included in `IList<T>` (along with those derived from `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`) I wonder if the `IList<T>` in .Net should actually be changed so that it inherits the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface rather than duplicating the members. Not that that helps you now.

Comment: `You should not implement both IList<T> and IReadOnlyList<T> in any class.` Does `List<T>` implement both of them?

Comment: Yes it does and I cannot imagine why!

Comment: There are many MSFT classes which implement both `IList<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>`, including `T[]` and `List<T>`. `IReadOnlyList<T>` couldn't inherit from `IList<T>` when it was introduced since that would have been a breaking change; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35940240/5985508).

Comment: @SteveHarris "I wonder if the `IList<T>` in .Net should actually be changed so that it inherits the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface rather than duplicating the members." -- [Yes, but that was impossible without breaking backwards compatibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35938995)

Comment: I see. It's quite a complicated matter then. So really, a time machine is required to solve that problem.