# Is there a readonly ISet-like interface?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is any set-like readonly interface that declares a `Contains` method in C#. I don't want to just implement the `ISet` interface because it has too many unnecessary methods.

My idea implementation would be like thi:

```
public class PositiveInt : IReadOnlySet<Int32>
{
   public bool Contains(Int32 n){
      return n > 0;
   }
}

public class CraEmployeeNames:IReadOnlySet<String>
{
   public bool Contains(String n){
      return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n) && n.StartsWith("Cra");
   }
}
```

I can define my own `IReadOnlySet`, but want to ensure there is no built-in one before I do.

Comment: Do you mean [ReadOnlyCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) keyword

Comment: It seems to me your are trying to validate your data. Why are you using this approach to validate your data values?

Comment: The readonly keyword is kind of useless here isn't it?

Comment: If you only want a `Contains` method you could just use a `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: Maybe, depends, this all sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Agreed, but suggesting readonly keyword when you don't know what the X is...?

Comment: Sadly, they didn't make an `IReadOnlySet<T>`, and if they did, it would likely have the vast majority of the methods you're complaining about having to implement. So create an `IContainsCollection<T> : ICollection<T> { Contains(T); }`, or implement `ISet<T>` partially with `NotImplementedException`s on the rest, or create `IContains<T> { Contains(T); }`, etc. etc. What are you trying to do? If you answer that, we can suggest something intelligently

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I would like to implement some kind of tester to test if an element is in a pre-defined---eh---set. So my sample implementation actually explains my intention quite clearly. I want to "declare" characteristics of a Set,  but not by add into it.

Comment: @WeiMa Then it sounds like my `IContains<T>` is all you need.

Comment: Your `IReadOnlySet`, if you make one, should also probably inherit from `IEnumerable`.  In addition to calling `Contains` on a read only set, one may want to iterate it.

Comment: But the mathematics definition of Set has no where mentioning that it should be "Enumerable", so I do see why I should inherit from IEnumerable.

Comment: It's true that a mathematical set might not be enumerable (e.g. the set of all real numbers), but `ISet<T>` is. If you use the name `IReadOnlySet<T>` in C#, I'd expect it to be similar to `ISet<T>` but read-only, which means `IEnumerable<T>` is implemented, `Count` exists, etc. Your examples do not appear to match this rule. (which is why I named it `IContains<T>` in my solution)

Comment: That is why probably IContains make more sense:) I already implemented it.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/InternalUtilities/IReadOnlySet.cs

Comment: This wouldn’t be such a big deal if `IReadOnlyCollection(T)` provided `Contains()` like `ICollection(T)` does. No idea why that’s missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Edit 17 September 2020*: .NET 5.0 now offers the new interface [IReadOnlySet<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlyset-1):

---

No, there is no `IReadOnlySet<T>` interface in C#. Based on the needs you've described, I think you should create your own `IContains<T>` interface.

```
public interface IContains<T>
{
    bool Contains(T item);
}
```

Note that this can not be added to existing collections like `List<T>` or `HashSet<T>`, and doesn't contain any other set-like operations like `Count` or enumeration. You might use it like:

```
public void TestContains<T>(IContains<T> container, T item)
{
    if (container.Contains(item))
    {
        //something
    }
    else
    {
        //something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

How about the [`IImmutableSet<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467169%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

It is in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk namespace.  See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sdk.sfc.ireadonlyset.aspx

I don't know why it is there, instead of with the rest of the IReadOnlyYadaYada<> interfaces in .NET itself.  Probably some snafu.  And probably, fear of collision is the reason they have not put it into .NET itself.  Which is a shame.

Also, see this question: [Why does List implement IReadOnlyList in .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262981/why-does-listt-implement-ireadonlylistt-in-net-4-5)

Comment: Late but solution is now available. It is a nuget package called System.Collections.Immutable

Comment: @MohsinSyed please consider responding to the question here and adding full details like type name etc.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 5 and above, [`IReadonlySet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlyset-1?view=net-6.0) is added. In this version of .Net, Microsoft has started to support **Immutality**. There are several classes and interfaces in [`System.Collections.Generic Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-6.0) to support immutable functionality. For instance you can use [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-6.0) which is one my favorites.

By the following code snippet, you can convert `IEnumerable<T>` to [`IReadOnlySet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlyset-1?view=net-6.0):

```
public static IReadOnlySet<T> ToReadOnlySet<T>([DisallowNull] this IEnumerable<T> items) => ImmutableList.CreateRange(items).ToHashSet();
```