# Why doesn't List<T> explicitly implement IReadOnlyList<T>?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I ask because I thought C# required all interfaces to be implemented in the class. Using ILSpy I found that IReadOnlyList.this[int index] indexer implementation wasn't in the class List.

***this is an edited snippet of the class declaration(not everything listed)***

```
public class List < T > : IList <T >, IReadOnlyList < T >
```

[image: List class declaration]

`IList<T>.this[int index]` is there, but not `IReadOnlyList<T>.this[int index]`.

[image: ILSpy search]

Just seems weird, how does this compile in the first place? Is there some special sauce in .NET Framework that enables this?

Comment: Why use ILSpy when you can see the source code? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: Even looking at the actual source code on reference source, I can't find any implementation of IReadOnlyList<T> on List<T>. It's not a partial class, there is only one code file for it.

Comment: @Alex.A - It's in the source. Line 174 is `public T this[int index]` and that implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: Ok. If the public indexer this[int index] implements IReadOnlyList<T>, why does it have a setter? IReadOnlyList<T> only defines an indexer with a getter. Wouldn't that normally fail compilation?

Comment: @Alex [Compiles just fine](http://rextester.com/TDGH79727). Not sure why you think it wouldn't - you have to implement what an interface requires. It doesn't mean you're restricted from implementing more.

Comment: @Alex.A no, you need to think of properties and indexers as just a convenience for calling a `Foo GetFoo()` and `void SetFoo(Foo value)` the interface only requires that the get method exists, it does not care if the set method is there or not.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that interfaces only specifies the minimum of what the class has to implement, not the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

I think the tool you're using is causing the confusion. The indexer in the list is not implemented explicitly as `IList` implementation.

```
public class List<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, ICollection, IList
{
    (...)
    public T this[int index] { get; set; }
```

Here's a simple snippet with a class that implements two interfaces to prove that it's OK to provide a single implementation for two interfaces.

```
    public interface IOne{void MyMethod();}

    public interface ITwo{void MyMethod();}

    public class MyClass: IOne, ITwo
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        new MyClass().MyMethod();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a pre-implemented type of `IReadOnlyCollection` or `IReadOnlyList` you can use `ReadOnlyCollection`. Please look at this sample code:

```
 public void Test()
    {
        IList<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 10, 20 };
        IReadOnlyList<int> myReadOnlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(myList);
        GetElement(myReadOnlyCollection,1);
    }


 private int GetElement(IReadOnlyList<int> list,int index)
    {
        return list[index];
    }

//Output: 10
```

Comment: Your answer seems to imply that `List` does not implement `IReadOnlyList`. That is incorrect. It does implement it. `Why did you expect to find the implementation of IReadOnlyList in List` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262981/why-does-listt-implement-ireadonlylistt-in-net-4-5