# Why does C# `List` implements `IReadOnlyCollection`?

Tags: c#, .net, list, immutability, readonly-collection

By looking at the documentation, between .NET Framework [v4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.0) and [v4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.5) the `List<T>` started implementing the `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface. The documentation of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` says:

> Represents a strongly-typed, read-only collection of elements.

I am confused on why `List` implements such an interface. After all, can't the list items be modified? I think I am likely misinterpreting the meaning of "read-only collection" in this context, but I do not understand how. For example, as the MSDN documentation states for the [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-7.0) ***class***:

> A collection that is read-only is simply a collection with a wrapper that prevents modifying the collection; therefore, if changes are made to the underlying collection, the read-only collection reflects those changes.

The `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` class in fact does not allow, for instance, to Add elements.

Furthermore, in later versions of .NET, some types have been introduced which are *explicitly* for immutable lists:

- [`IImmutableList<T>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.iimmutablelist-1?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.5) although introduced much later, in .NET 6.
- For the class [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-6.0), the documentation says: *When you add or remove items from an immutable list, a copy of the original list is made with the items added or removed, and the original list is unchanged.*
- The [`ImmutableArray<T>` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray-1?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.5) is another example.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does List<T> implement IReadOnlyList<T> in .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262981/why-does-listt-implement-ireadonlylistt-in-net-4-5) (found by googling the **title** of your question)

Comment: Google is better for searching existing StackOverflow posts than StackOverflow search! I thought the opposite would be true... :(

Comment: [This](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6352844/198123250-b716cb75-cd12-4c3e-86ca-d46df34de74d.png) is what can be seen by searchig with SO. Before posting and wasting time writing the question, I also searched with SO search other combinations of the terms. This is really disappointing. Next time I will use Google to search for duplicates instead.